# Does the persisted file load in RAM memory after startup?

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-map

We are very interested in using Chronicle Map in our project. Currently, we're trying to understand how to work with a persisted file. For example when I create Chronicle Map with

```
 ChronicleMap.of(String.class, String.class)
    .createPersistedTo(persistedFile)
```

Is data from persistedFile will be loaded into RAM memory? Or it will be served from the disk.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the data from the persistedFile will be loaded into RAM memory

No, the memory mappings will only load the blocks, as they are required rather than loading in the whole file. But this is a technicality, you can use chronicle-map as though it was all in memory as chronicle-map handles the memory mappings for you.

Comment: To clarify, it is served from disk as needed, and while in memory, it is not loaded again. This reduces startup time and allows maps to exceed main memory size by several times. +1

Comment: @PeterLawrey - If the ChroniceMap is built with `create()` rather than `createPersistedTo()` is it still backed with a (temporary) file, i.e. can the map still exceed main memory size?

Comment: @dab.m without a file, native memory uses your memory + swap space and it depends on how much of those are free.